# Component nesting in DevExtreme jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress, devextreme

Help, please, I study DevExpress and I cannot understand something. How can I nest components? For example, so that dxAccordion in one of the items contains one more dxAccordion. I've seen it written like this: widget: 'dxAccordion' and then the nested component will become the accordion when the parent is rendered. But it doesn't work.
It should look something like this:

```
const items = [
    {widget:'dxButton', options:{text:'Button'}},
    {widget:'dxCalendar', options:{firstDayOfWeek:1}}
];

$('dx-acc').dxAccordion({
    dataSource: items
})
```

And I would like the button and calendar to be automatically added to the accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use item templates. Please refer to [this documentation topic](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/Accordion/Customize_Item_Appearance/). There is also a corresponding [demo](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Accordion/Overview/jQuery/Light/).